# Cannot download png with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, download

I have been using the following method successfully for a while now, but a problem has emerged.

```
        public string downloadfiletoclient()
    {   
        string SessionId = HttpContext.Current.Session["SessionVar_ID"].ToString();

        Response.Clear();
        string outPath = "";




            if (!Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/User_Generated_Content/" + SessionId)))
            {
                return "-1";
            }

            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/User_Generated_Content/" + SessionId));

            var fileName = directory.GetFiles().OrderByDescending(f => f.LastWriteTime).First();

            outPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/User_Generated_Content/" + SessionId + "/" + fileName.ToString());
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
        }

        Response.WriteFile(outPath);
        Response.End();

        return "1";
```

The method now doesn't work for the png files I am generating.  It used to work, but I have since switched to a new control which is generating the images.  The method still works for .xls files.  I have no idea what is going on.  No error messages are generated.  Things look fine.  Just the file donwload never initiates within the browser.

Please Help, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: I don't understand this code. Can you explain what you are trying to do? The first `if` block is neverr executed because you are setting the hidden field value to -1...so what's the point in having an if block if the value of this hidden field is always -1?

Comment: That is a mistake, I will get rid of that, its the code in the else block that is the focus.  It runs.  My application generates various files for download based on user input, the file might be an excel srpeadsheet or a png.  After the file is generated the code in the else block runs which finds the most recent file in the directory and downloads it to the user.  It works with the spread sheet, not with the pngs. It used to work with pngs from a different source.  I have verified that the png file is in the server directory.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure why the issue with png files only, it's a bit strange. But, I'd suggest you to debug your application and see exactly what's being sent to the client. Furthermore,  since you're "attaching" the file to the response I would also set the content type to octet-stream. Give it a go

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` may help...